# Using Grand Central Dispatch to convert URL string from JSON into image for ImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, imageview, grand-central-dispatch

Among other data (specifically strings), I've got a URL being pulled from JSON and saved in the array "jsonArray". I need the the URL (which is for an image dependent on the user signed in) to be converted into an actual image ready to be displayed in my imageview "imageProfPic". I'm not that familiar with GCD, so I'd greatly appreciate any and all help with my code and getting my image successfully displayed in imageProfPic.

**(EDIT: Forgot to mention that I'm getting the error "_NSCFString isFileURL")**

**TableViewController.m file**

```
    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://domain.com/json2.php"];
    NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
    NSError *error;

    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    [tableView reloadData]; // if tableView is unidentified make the tableView IBOutlet
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return jsonArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NeedCardTableViewCell *cell = (NeedCardTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"needCard" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *needs = jsonArray[indexPath.row]; // get the data dict for the row
    cell.textNeedTitle.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needTitle"];
    cell.textNeedPoster.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needPoster"];
    cell.textNeedDescrip.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needDescrip"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("imageQueue", NULL), ^{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:needs[@"userImage"]]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell.imageProfPic setImage:image];
        });
    });

    return cell;
```

**TableViewController.h file**

```
@interface NeedCardTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textNeedTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textNeedPoster;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textNeedDescrip;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageProfPic;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Comment: Have you checked the url you've been trying to get the image from to make sure it has a valid image?

Comment: @Inertiatic yes, it is valid.

Comment: Look at the [SDWEBIMAGE](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). It may helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to create a NSURL with your string and you should be good. Give this a go:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:needs[@"userImage"]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell.imageProfPic setImage:image];
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This took 3 SO questions to figure out! I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked for you, such a small little detail that is easy to overlook since the NSString is a "url"

Comment: @dvdowns Unfortunately, this fixes only one error. The other error still exists (due to the fact that a cell being reused, and has been re-assigned a different row when the completion handler executes) ;)   Since this error is the second most question on SO, I'm confident the OP will find a solution from one of the 15 thousand answers, though  :)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Since I posted this answer, I've gotten rid of all the GCD and gone with AFNetworking. Once I got it installed, it worked like a charm. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is displaying the image from a JSON, I used [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and it easily works with me.

**Using UIImageView+WebCache category with UITableView**

Just #import the UIImageView+WebCache.h header, and call the setImageWithURL:placeholderImage: method from the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: UITableViewDataSource method. Everything will be handled for you, from async downloads to caching management.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
return cell;
```

}

**Using blocks**

With blocks, you can be notified about the image download progress and whenever the image retrival has completed with success or not:

```
// Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                  completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {... completion code here ...}];
```

Comment: I've tried this code snippet myself when I visited the SDWebImage GitHub site earlier. Thanks, but I'm just not as familiar with libraries, I'm also not sure who to implement this into my code/situation specifically.

Comment: download the library, and paste it on your project make sure you to check "copy item into destination group" and on your TableViewController.m file import UIImageView+WebCache.h then you are good to go.